# Особенности записи нескольких строк в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Есть следующий цикл:

```
$res = false;
        foreach($options['properties'] as $o) {
            $prop_val = $o['prop_val'];
            $prop_id  = $o['prop_id'];
            $res .= "(`$id`, `$prop_id`, `$prop_val`),";
        };
```

Он добавляет в $res несколько параметров, которые нужно записать в таблицу. Результат его работы (var_dump) такой:

```
string(39) "(`41`, `6`, `55`),(`41`, `5`, `16см`)"
```

Проблема заключается в том, что если в $res есть символы, а не цифры, то ни одна из строк вообще не запишется. Вопрос - почему и как с этим быть? SQL-запрос:

> $sql = "
>               INSERT INTO `product_prop`(`product_id`,`property_id`,`value`) VALUES {$res}
>           ";

Как записать в БД значения из $res вместе с символами?

Comment: Почему проще сразу в цикле в базу не писать по 1 запросу?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan сделал все в рамках цикла, все равно не записывает строки с символами :(

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста определение таблицы 'product_prop', какой тип у поля 'value'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается так

**mysqli**

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO product_prop (product_id,property_id,value) VALUES(?,?,?)');
$id=null;
$prop_val=null;
$prop_id=null;

$stmt->bind_param("iii", $id, $prop_id, $prop_val);

foreach($options['properties'] as $o){
    $id=41;
    $prop_val = $o['prop_val'];
    $prop_id  = $o['prop_id'];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

**PDO**

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO product_prop (product_id, property_id, value) VALUES(:product_id, :property_id, :value)');
$id=null;
$prop_id=null;
$prop_val=null;
$stmt->bindParam(':product_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':property_id', $prop_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $prop_val, PDO::PARAM_INT);

foreach($options['properties'] as $o){
    $id=41;
    $prop_val = $o['prop_val'];
    $prop_id  = $o['prop_id'];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Сделал так, пишет: Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: спасибо огромное!